# Creating an array of hashes from user input in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, block, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to create a simple bank account program to practice some Ruby.  The idea is to create an array of hashes.  However, I want to use user input to create a new hash, whether that be creating the title or simply numbering the entries something like user1 or user2.

If I use a set up that stores the username, pin, and balance all inside the hash, like so:

```
jhip = {
  :pin => 1234,
  :balance => 1000000
}

jdog = {
  :pin => 2345,
  :balance => 1000
}

accounts = [
  jhip,
  jdog
]
```

I feel it will be much easier to find the right username in the array and/or tell the user that their name has already been chosen than if I used a set up like this:

```
user1 = {
  :username => "jhip",
  :pin => 1234,
  :balance => 1000000
}

user2 = {
  :username => "jdog",
  :pin => 2345,
  :balance => 1000
}

accounts = [
  user1,
  user2
]
```

The real meat of this problem is getting the user input to be the title of the hash.  I know the notation for creating a hash like this:

```
h = hash.new #or
hash = {}
```

But I don't know how to use the input as a title.  When I store the input as a variable, I can play with the variable:

```
@username = gets.chomp
@username.to_i #or any method
```

But if I try to create a hash with the variable name, I overwrite the input.

```
@username = {} #no more using the response from gets
```

I guess what I'm looking for would be something like

```
@username = gets.chomp
@username.to_s => (some sort of code or command I'm unaware of) {}
```

And then I can push the key and value pairs into the hash.  I don't know if I could use a block to accomplish this or something else.  I'm still new to this, so I apologize if I bit off more than I can chew with this problem.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will create a hash with the username key assigned based on user input:

```
puts "Hey what's your username?"
username = gets.chomp
user = {
  username: username,
  pin: 10,
  balance: 100
}
puts "Your account is: #{user}"
```

Similarly, the following will insert a new hash into an array of hashes with the username key assigned based on user input:

```
def create_user(username)
  {
    username: username,
    pin: 10,
    balance: 100
  }
end

accounts = []
puts "Hey what's your username?"
username = gets.chomp
accounts.push(create_user(username))
puts "There are #{accounts.length} accounts"
```

In order to find an element in the array, you can simply iterate through each element and return if that element's username matches the correct username. For example

```
accounts = [create_user('alice'), create_user('bob')]

def find_by_username(accounts, username)
  accounts.each do |user|
    return user if user[:username] == username
  end
  nil
end

puts find_by_username(accounts, 'alice')
puts find_by_username(accounts, 'bob')
puts find_by_username(accounts, 'charles')
```

This method will iterate through each user and return the user if the username matches the given username. If no such user exists, it will return `nil`.

Ruby is nice in that a lot of those types of actions have been abstracted out -- arrays respond to a `find` method that returns the first element that matches a code block, or nil if no such element exists. So an alternate implementation of `find_by_username` would be

```
def find_by_username2(accounts, username)
  accounts.find do |user|
    user[:username] == username
  end
end
```

or more concisely

```
def find_by_username3(accounts, username)
  accounts.find { |user| user[:username] == username }
end
```

However looping through an array of hashes every time you want to find a user by username is a relatively slow operation. If you were to instead have a hash of hashes, the data structure might look like this:

```
accounts = {
  "alice" => { pin: 312, balance: -100 },
  "bob"   => { pin: 104, balance: 1000 }
}
```

and you would be able to find a user with the username of "bob" with `accounts["bob"]`

Comment: Wow, that's so simple.  How would I go about searching for the user in the array you created?  Say someone wants to check the balance, you ask them the username in the same manner.  I'm assuming I wouldn't type accounts[username:]

Comment: That update was really helpful.  I learned recently that searching through a hash only takes one iteration, so the time would be drastically reduced as you mentioned.  I'll be changing my little program to incorporate that.